# Can I have canonical links that show to latest version?

Tags: docusaurus

I use documentation versioning on my site. I've noticed that some versions of docs rank higher on Google than the latest version of the docs.

I wouldn't discourage google from indexing, although that might be the only solution when I think of it, but I wonder if some kind of canonical linking is possible. At the moment in the version docs I can see:

```
<link data-rh="true" rel="canonical" href="https://myserver.com/docs/product/1.2.1/functions"><link data-rh="true" rel="alternate" href="https://myserver.com/docs/product/1.2.1/functions" hreflang="en">
```

Can I have canonical to show to the current URL `https://my server.com/docs/product/functions`?